# optimizing mmap on very large file

Tags: c, algorithm, mmap

I have a very large file 150 GB. I use read-only `mmap` and I perform binary search into the file.

Currently binary search perform quite slow.

However I am thinking of following optimization - when I check (disk seek) some value, all values "around" this value are already into the memory because they belong to same disk block. Instead of jumping somewhere else in the file, I can check "near" values and jump after that.

Is this optimization worth doing it?

Also how I can estimate where disk block "ends".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have stumbled upon the line of reasoning that leads to the [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) data structure.  The optimization you are imagining *is* worth doing, but to get as much as possible out of it, you will need to reorganize the data on disk substantially and use more complicated algorithms than binary search.  You should probably look into existing open source B-tree libraries rather than implementing from scratch.

Because you are using `mmap`, the minimum granularity of access is not the disk block size, but the memory "page" size, which can be queried with [`sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sysconf).  Some OSes will read and populate a larger chunk of memory on random access to a file-backed region, but I don't know of any portable way to find out how much.  You might also get some benefit from [`madvise(MADV_RANDOM)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise).

Comment: Another direction that this line of reasoning can lead to is cache-oblivious data structures.  These do not require you to know page size...and also take advantages of multiple levels of CPU cache.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devdev/2007/06/12/cache-oblivious-data-structures/ for more.

Comment: `madvise(MADV_RANDOM)` speed it up 60%. Nice, but still slow.